# SQL display total on the first row only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display my data like this

```
Name             Product         Amount     Total
_______________________________________________
John Smith     Burger          60.00      100.00
John Smith     Fries           40.00      
Michael Smith  Burger          60.00      60.00
```

Comment: I'm using MSSQL

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention your DBMS so this is ANSI standard SQL:

```
select name, product, amount, 
       case 
         when row_Number() over (partition by name order by ????) = 1 then 
            sum(amount) over (partition by name)
       end as total
from the_table
order by name, ???;
```

Note that there is no such thing as "the first row" in a relational database. To identify the first one, you need a column that defines your order and that you can use for the `order by`. You need to replace both `???` with that column from your table

Comment: Thank you. I will try this one now.

Comment: This works with SQL server? If so, I have learnt something new!!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this using window functions, but you have to be very careful.  The problem is the ordering of the results and the definition oft he first row.

Let me attempt a stable sort using `name`, `amount`, and `product`:

```
select name, amount, product,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by name order by amount desc, product) = 1
             then sum(amount) over (partition by name)
        end) as total
from t
order by name, amount desc, product;
```

It is very important to have the same `order by` keys in the outer query and for the window functions.

Comment: Thank you, it's working. But how about if I want to display a specific data only on the first row of each group? I'm trying to display a function based data.

Comment: @carlosuarez . . . Just use `row_number()` to identify the "first" row.  You need to be careful that the outer `order by` has exactly the same ordering, to be sure the values are indeed on the "first" row.